# Having Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different

Tags: javascript, react-native, api

I'm having **Error Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different** while connecting API. Below I have attached the error screenshot and the code. Please do help me out.

**Error Screenshot:**

[image]

```
 const { myToken } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [pendingApiData, setPendingApiData] = React.useState([]); 
    const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

    const FetchList = () => {
        const abortCont = new AbortController();
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: URLs._pendingReceipt,
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                Authorization: myToken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            signal: abortCont.signal,
        }).then(function (result) { 
            setPendingApiData(result.data.pendingData);

        }).catch(function (error) {
            Alert.alert("Error", error);
        });
        setIsFetching(false);
        return () => abortCont.abort(); 
    }

    useEffect (() => { 
        FetchList();
    }, []);

    const onRefresh = () => {
        setIsFetching(true);
        FetchList(); 
    };
```

Comment: is there animation related code running on this screen?

Comment: No abhishek. There is no animation

Comment: Can you try to comment catch  Alert.alert("Error", error); and check again @vesh.